# Why does my computer hesitate to turn on?

Tags: motherboard, computer-building, power, pause

I just built my first computer, but every time I hit the power button everything goes on like it was starting up, then everything turns off for about 3 seconds, and then it turns on and stays on.  Is this just something my motherboard does, or is this an error that puts my computer at risk when I turn it on?

- Asus P8P67 Deluxe
- Intel Core i7 2600K Sandy Bridge 3.4 GHz
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 570
- Cooler Master 690
- 500 GB SATA
- 800W Power supply
- RAM

Comment: For me it did this only once and after each time I set the BIOS settings. Usually when the computers stay out after turning on, there's a short circuit somewhere. But it goes back on, so I don't really know an answer to this.

Comment: It get's worse if you get random reboots like I had, most likely caused by my PSU not being powerful enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal, I have 2 different types and manufacturer of motherboard in my computer room that do this (Intel server S5000XVN & Asus P5-Q). I think it's part of a safe power on process.

Comment: Especiall if it's the fans turning up after the CMOS beep - modern motherboards usually perform a fan test at startup for the user to make sure they're all working.

Comment: indeed, same behaviour here. If the fans dont spin up it'll (hopefully) power down before damage occurs.

Comment: That's a relief.  Still annoying, though.  Thanks everyone!