# CPU LED stays red. Is this a motherboard or CPU issue?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I put together a new PC. It ran fine for an evening but after that it suddenly shut down. I discovered that there was some thermal paste underneath the CPU; I cleaned it off carefully with some rubbing alcohol. The PC then worked again for a couple of hours but then shut off again. Ever since, it mostly doesn't boot, except for the three or four times it does - but gives up after a few minutes.

System:

- Asus P8P67 Pro
- Intel i5-2500
- ATI Radeon 6850
- Corsair Vengeance 2x4GB
- 1TB 7200 RPM hard drive
- Cooler Master GX 550W

Both of the power cords to the motherboard are connected. I tried with one stick of RAM and exchanging them, but it didn't make a difference.

I also tried reseating the CPU and checked for bent pins.

Does anyone have a clue? I am out of ideas.

Comment: Did you check to make sure that there wasn't thermal paste in the CPU socket?

Comment: yes, i did, all clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the **PSU** was not efficient enough for this motherboard/cpu. All voltages were what they were supposed to be but there was something else off, not sure what. The guy in  the store didn't even know, except that his equipment pointed out that there was something not right. So replaced it with a cheaper (Antec basic 430W) and it posted immediately!

Answer (score 1):

I had a friend build a computer with the exact same board. He had a very similar problem. He did notice some smoke when he plugged it up the first time that came from the Motherboard(near the RAM slots) when he powered it on.

If you noticed anything like that I would put money on it that it is the board.
Hopefully if you got the board from a place like NewEgg they will let you return it for another one.

Comment: hmm, i didn't notice anything like that. The first time i powered it up, i forgot to plug in the 2nd power cable. But after that it started up just fine, and didn't show any issue until the day after.

Answer (score 0):

P8P67 series have been know for difficulties to start ("double post") and sudden freeze without BSOD. I happen to be one of those happy customers. It took me a couple of months to find a BIOS configuration that allowed to bypass this problem.

See: [Why does my computer hesitate to turn on?](https://superuser.com/questions/238815/why-does-my-computer-hesitate-to-turn-on/329546#329546)